# How to break out of a for loop while inside of a function? (node.js)

Tags: javascript

I'm using this library: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

Here's an example of my code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redisdb = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client
var multi = redisdb.multi();

redisdb.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected to redis');
});

redisdb.flushdb(function(err, success) {
    if (success) {
        console.log('cleared redis DB');
    }
});

redisdb.sadd("list", "list:1");
redisdb.sadd("list:1", "list:1:stuff:abc");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:2");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:3");
redisdb.sadd("list:3", "list:3:stuff:def");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:4");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:5");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:6");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:7");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:8");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:9");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:10");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:11");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:12");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:13");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:14");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:15");

var abc = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    /*
    returns:
    [ 'list:3' ]
    [ 'list:1' ]
*/
}

redisdb.smembers('list', function(err, mems) {
            if (mems && mems.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < mems.length; i++) {
                    redisdb.scard(mems[i], function(err, data) {
                        if (data > 0) {
                        abc(this.args); //would like it if the loop stopped here
                    }
                    });
                }
            }
            });
```

I want the loop to stop from the moment that I call on the function `abc`. Therefore in that case it would only return `[ 'list:3' ]`.

How would I be able to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that function executed asynchronously? That means, that the entire loop have been executed before even the first call to that callback would occur.

Comment: @Teemu I'm honestly not sure. Is there no way to trigger it synchronously?

Comment: @marshalcraft Fair point, it's just I've used loops a lot before and this is the first time I've had this sort of issue. (and I assume it's because of redis functions being asynchronous) So I thought the more detail the better.

Comment: At Teemu, what function? If it is asynch or times out and switches to asynch it should say.

Comment: @marshalcraft The anonymous callback function in which OP wants to break the loop.

Comment: You should abstract the programng problem from your very explicit problem, a lot of unessesary information. Also see a few JavaScript tutorials on loops. Also some consider breaking in a for loop poor practise, meaning you don't have to do that. One way is to declare a book along with your index and add a requirement that it ne false along with index requirement. Then when find string set to true. Probably better ways but I'm not great with js. Like for(x=0,found=true;x<index&&found==false;x++)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a break in right after your abc call:

```
if (data > 0) {
  abc(this.args)
  break
}
```

`break` will exit a loop.

Comment: Got this error: `/var/www/public/nodetesting/stackeg.js:48
                        break;
                        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: Yep. I overlooked that you were inside a function. You can return from your function, but you can't break from inside it. My bad.

Comment: I've tried using `return;` and it still returns `[ 'list:3' ] [ 'list:1' ]` so it's not stopping the loop :(

Comment: Yeah, you want to be able to break a loop from inside a function, but your function is also async, so I'm not sure how that is going to work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data > 0) {
                    abc(this.args); //would like it if the loop stopped here
                    return;  
                }

or 

 if (data > 0) {
                    abc(this.args); //would like it if the loop stopped here
                    i= mems.length; //Not a best practice 
                }
```

Comment: Both still return `[ 'list:3' ]
[ 'list:1' ]`

Comment: This should work also, but to be more clear you could use a separate variable. Anything you want to do differently needs to be done after signaling to break. Unless you re write every time and use last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0, var found = false; i < Mena.index &&  found   == false; i ++) 
{
   //your stuff...
   if(data>0) 
   {
      //your stuff...
      found = true; //break
   }
 }
```

This is pretty basic algorithm stuff and similar for all c syntax programing languages. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp